# How to quickly unbind an event wherever it's attached?

Tags: jquery

I've bound a couple events like so:

```
$('#window-overlay').on('click', overlayClickHandler);
$clickedObj.on('click', overlayClickHandler);
```

Is there some easy way so that if I click on one of these things, the click event is removed from the other thing? Removing it from `#window-overlay` is simple enough, but $clickedObj is a variable within an `if` block, so later on it may be difficult to figure out what object the handler was bound to.

Comment: I think the only way to solve this without adding a class or data attribute to every element with this event handler is to search through every element in the dom looking for ones with said event bound. `$("*").off("click", overlayClickHandler);`

Comment: I have an Idea, but please add some more code to your question -esp. the said if-block, so where exactly is the handler bound?

Answer (score 1):

maintain an array of the jquery objects that you want to unbind the event for and based on your condition you can go through the array and unbind the ones necessary... You can use a neat json structure as the array value to help you distinguish between the different bound events.. something like

```
{
eventType: "click",
category: "myCategory1",
object: jqueryObject //or store the  selector if you want to keep a low memory footprint..
}
```

Category is basically used to group related events, so that you unbind only the ones necessary.

I am not sure if there is an easier alternative but this is one approach, at least it is better than finding all controls with events bound on them